# How is this question unclear?

Tags: discussion, support, close-reasons

How is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/194320/wifi-not-working-after-a-fresh-install-of-arch-linux unclear? Both in the title and then in

> this markdown environment I ask the question again being more specific.

I cannot fix a question when the close reason doesn't quite jive with the post. Additionally, the hold reason says add detail. I have added all the pertinent detail I believe. If something else is needed, no one has asked for further clarification, so without feedback, I can't improve the post anymore as well.

Answer (score 4):

I voted to close as unclear for two primary reasons: first, despite repeatedly being asked to connect manually, which would have generated meaningful error messages at the appropriate points, you declined to do so. Without that information, the question is essentially unanswerable.

And secondly, because the edit history of the questions shows more and more irrelevant information being added to the question, making it harder and harder to read and *decreasing* the likelihood of anyone being able to answer (or the question being of any value for future visitors).

I included a link in one of my comments to the relevant section of the Arch wiki; follow that methodically and include exactly where it fails and any error messages and remove all of the extraneous material from the existing question and it would be a candidate for reopening.

Comment: I followed your link and added the information out puts from the link. I sectioned each output with code blocks so it would be easier to read. So that extraneous material comes from your link.

Comment: You did not. Reread the page, from the start, and follow it methodically.

Comment: You are in no place to tell me what I have and haven't done. Learn some respect.

Comment: @dustin Jason is being respectful and is trying to help you. The edit history reflects what he's telling you.

Comment: @slm someone who says I didn't do something is not being respectful. How do they know what I have done? It is am assumption and disrespectful. Please tell me how this user knows what I have done? He wasn't at my house when accessed the link.

Comment: @dustin under every question and answer on the site is an edit link. If you click it if shows you the entire history of edits that occurred and who did the editing and when they did it. Jason is referring to this. I've known Jason for several years and he's most certainly trying to help you. Try not to take his words so personally. Much can be lost in toneless text.

Comment: @slm this isn't the first SE site I have used. He is speaking of a link to an arch Linux wiki not edit history.

Comment: @dustin he's basing it on the updates you've provided compared to the info you've provided thus far on your original question.

Comment: BTW @Dustin I looked at your profile page now. I thought you didn't understand that but seeing your work on the other sites I see you understood that point now.

Comment: @Dustin, at any rate I'd go thru what's in that link and details in your question and double check everything one more time.

Comment: @slm I am not going to do that. I just won't be using this SE. I despise pompous individuals. No one who isn't with me knows what I have or haven't done so to claim otherwise is false.

Comment: @dustin The simplest way to back up your claim would be to edit the detail into your question, but you seem unwilling to do that so carping about it here is pointless.